# Make my jquery shorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like shorten my jQuery. I know this is possible using this element and child but I don't know how it works.

I have an element being shown and hidden on click, basically. They all have the same ID, just different classes.

How is it possible to achieve this?

This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<div id="spotparent">

  <div id="spot"  class="one" style="position: absolute; z-index: 103; width: 25px; height:25px;">
          <div id="ball"></div>
          <div id="pulse"></div>

          <div id="contentspot" class="one">
                    <img src="img/line-boost.png">

          </div>
        </div>

<div id="spot" class="two"  style="position: absolute; z-index: 103; width: 25px; height: 25px;">
          <div id="ball"></div>
          <div id="pulse"></div>

          <div id="contentspot" class="two">
                    <img src="img/line-tpu.png">

          </div>
        </div>

          <div id="spot"  class="three" style="position: absolute; z-index: 103; width: 25px; height:25px;">
          <div id="ball"></div>
          <div id="pulse"></div>

          <div id="contentspot" class="three">
                    <img src="img/line-wrap.png">

          </div>
        </div>

            <div id="spot"  class="four" style="position: absolute; z-index: 103; width: 25px; height:25px;">
          <div id="ball"></div>
          <div id="pulse"></div>

          <div id="contentspot" class="four">
                    <img src="img/line-support.png">

          </div>
        </div>

         <div id="spot"  class="five" style="position: absolute; z-index: 103; width: 25px; height:25px;">
          <div id="ball"></div>
          <div id="pulse"></div>

          <div id="contentspot" class="five">
                    <img src="img/line.png">

          </div>
        </div>

         <div id="spot"  class="six" style="position: absolute; z-index: 103; width: 25px; height:25px;">
          <div id="ball"></div>
          <div id="pulse"></div>

          <div id="contentspot" class="six">
                    <img src="img/line-knit.png">

          </div>
        </div>


         <div id="spot"  class="seven" style="position: absolute; z-index: 103; width: 25px; height:25px;">
          <div id="ball"></div>
          <div id="pulse"></div>

          <div id="contentspot" class="seven">
                    <img src="img/line-signature.png">

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

The point is on click of a spot id, the id 'contentspot' show ( by toggling a class who change the display from none to block).

for this I'm using the following JQuery:

```
$('#spot.one').click(function() {
             // if($('.hide').hasClass('test')){

  $('#contentspot.one').toggleClass('showcontent');

});


$('#spot.two').click(function() {
             // if($('.hide').hasClass('test')){

  $('#contentspot.two').toggleClass('showcontent');

});

$('#spot.three').click(function() {
             // if($('.hide').hasClass('test')){

  $('#contentspot.three').toggleClass('showcontent');

});

$('#spot.four').click(function() {
             // if($('.hide').hasClass('test')){

  $('#contentspot.four').toggleClass('showcontent');

});

$('#spot.five').click(function() {
             // if($('.hide').hasClass('test')){

  $('#contentspot.five').toggleClass('showcontent');

});

$('#spot.six').click(function() {
             // if($('.hide').hasClass('test')){

  $('#contentspot.six').toggleClass('showcontent');

});

$('#spot.seven').click(function() {
             // if($('.hide').hasClass('test')){

  $('#contentspot.seven').toggleClass('showcontent');

});
```

So it get repeated the all time.

I'm sure it's possible to make all this code in 2 lines. If anybody can explain the process for me to understand, it would be fantastic!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Shortening jQuery code is too common of a request to be a useful title on this site. Please reticle your question to state what the code accomplishes, as stated in the [ask] guidelines. Also, I suggest making a live demo by pressing Ctrl-M in the question editor.

Answer (score 4):

Before even looking at the JavaScript: You're misusing the `id` and `class` attributes!

IDs should preferably be unique across the whole document. But you have a whole bunch of elements all called `spot`. This is the exact wrong way to use IDs.

Conversely, class names *are* meant to be used for multiple elements that are in some way similar; elements that are of the same *class*. But here you're using different class names all the way through (`one`, `two`, etc.), negating the entire purpose of class names.

Also, class names (and IDs) should ideally be *descriptive*. Calling them `one`, `two` and so on doesn't explain anything about what they represent. If anything they tell you something about their order, but that's also not great because that's a presentation concern. Saying what order something goes in doesn't tell you much about what it represents or what makes it unique (and besides, their order is given from where they appear in the HTML).

The story repeats itself for the child elements, which also use IDs where they should use classes, and vice-versa. Again, this is exactly wrong.

You should at the very least swap the ID and class attributes around. What do the elements have in common? They're `spot`s - so that's their *class*. In what way are they unique? Well, right now it's their ordering, so the IDs should be `one`, `two`, and so on. But, as mentioned, that's already given by their relative placement in the HTML. And simply numbering them isn't great, so you should find a more descriptive name if you can. (If you do *need* to number something, add an actual number, like `foo1`, `foo2`, and so on. That makes it a lot easier to handle in JavaScript, since you can do things like `"#foo" + (n + 1)` to dynamically reference the IDs. JavaScript doesn't speak English, so spelling out the numbers makes everything more difficult.)

However, you don't need to use IDs for anything here. Since all the elements should behave the same way, there's no reason to treat them as unique. They all look and behave the same, so they're all of the same *class* - at least as far I can tell.

Speaking of CSS, move that to a `<style></style>` element or separate file instead of having it in the body of the HTML. HTML provides *structure*, JS provides *behavior*, and CSS provides *presentation*. Ideally they're orthogonal, i.e. you'll be able to change one without affecting the others. But not if it's all a big jumble.

Anyway, the JS:

```
// attach a click handler to all elements of the 'spot' class
$('.spot').on('click', function () {
  // 'this' is the element that was click, so find its first
  // descendant of the 'content' class, and show it
  $(this).find('.content:first').toggleClass('showcontent');
});
```

Note here, that instead of `contentspot` I've just called it `content`. Calling it "content *spot*" is redundant, since it's already nested inside a `spot` element. So all in all your HTML should look more like this:

```
<div class="spot"> <!-- move CSS to a style-element or separate file -->
  <div class="ball"></div>
  <div clas="pulse"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="img/line-boost.png">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- repeat as necessary -->
```

And you CSS (now separated from the body of the document) could look like:

```
.spot { // applies to all element with the "spot" class
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 103;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

Also, I'm guessing here that the `showcontent` class (which is redundantly named) simply changes the `display` CSS attribute. If that's the case, you probably don't need the class, and can just use jQuery's `toggle` instead:

```
$('.spot').on('click', function () {
  $(this).find('.content:first').toggle();
});
```

In any case, no repetition of JS or CSS, and no need for IDs as far as I can tell.

---

Alternatively, you can add a class to the `spot` element itself, and use CSS to describe how that affects its descendants:

```
$('.spot').on('click', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

And CSS:

```
.spot .content {
  display: none; // content is normally hidden
}.

.spot.active .content {
  display: block; // content is shown if the spot has the 'active' class
}
```

This moves more of the presentation concerns to the CSS, where it belongs.

Comment: Hi Flambino,

it makes all totally sense, thanks a lot !!

I have 2 small issues if you can help me out ?

When i click to one .spot, the .content display - fine

after that If i click to another spot, I'd like the previous spot to close automatically. IS there a way around this ?

As well I tried to change the click function by "hover" and it doesnt seems to work . .any idea ?

Thanks for all your help !!

Comment: @tibewww You could add a line to hide all the other `.content`-elements: `var localContent = $(this).find('content:first'); $('.content').not(localContent).hide(); localContent.show();` For future reference, though, "how do I ...?" questions should go to StackOverflow; CodeReview is for already-working code